# How to get CKEditor5 rich text content to display on frontend?

Tags: vuejs2, ckeditor, strapi, ckeditor5

I have a Vue website using the Strapi CMS. I added the CKEditor5 for my WYSIWYG editor for rich text, and it works fine on the backend. However, when I view the text on the frontend, it shows the markdown of what I wrote/edited rather than the HTML that it should.

I've looked at the documentation, and just am completely stuck. Below is what it displays as and how I'm calling it in in the code. Obviously there's something I'm not doing, I just have no clue what. Any help is appreciated.

**CODE**

```
<div>
{{Resource.attributes.body}}
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was something obvious...
Fixed it by utilization the `v-html` attribute.